# android when i use selector for my button, it crashes

Tags: android, button, onclick, crash, selector

## Problem solved!
In my relativelayout tag i defined android:onClick...
I deleted that and it works, thanks for your helps!

When i use selector for my button, my application crashed...
I will be crazy.. I researched on internet but i didn't find the real solution

My button code:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/ib_login"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_password"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login_selector" />
```

My selector code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_onclick"
        />
<item   android:drawable="@drawable/button"/>

</selector>
```

And my logcat:

```
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method res/drawable-hdpi/button_onclick.png(View) in the activity class com.kisirdongu.denemeapp.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.RelativeLayout with id 'container'
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3031)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: res/drawable-hdpi/button_onclick.png [class android.view.View]
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3024)
04-18 06:52:37.084: E/AndroidRuntime(608):  ... 11 more
```

*Whole layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#C7C7C7"
android:onClick="@drawable/button_onclick"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.kisirdongu.denemeapp.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_password"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_username"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="*****"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:password="true"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ib_login"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_password"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login_selector" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_login"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ib_login"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp" 
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pb_login"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:text="Logging in..." 
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_username"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_password"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="username"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:singleLine="true" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_user"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="User Login"
    android:textColor="#333"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*My drawable forlder:

http://puu.sh/8dlOx.png

Thanks for your helps!

Comment: Are you sure that it is caused because of this button? Can you post you whole layout?

Comment: Are you sure you have an image called `button_onclick.png` in your drawable folders, spelled correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android:onClick="@drawable/button_onclick"` line in your `RelativeLayout` causes the problem. It expects the name of a method, but you are passing a drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you need to define all three states when creating a custom background i.e default, pressed and focused button. Also make sure that you have Nine-patch bitmap for your image
You have defined only two, here's an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```

For more help go here
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

Comment: I don't think you have to define all three states, just one pressed and one default should be fine

Comment: well , check the link I have given, it is the offical android doc , there's a sub heading "Custom Background", it states there that you need three states, also make sure that the images are Nine Patch bitmaps

Comment: According to the guidelines you should define all of them, but it should compile if you have less.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:onClick="@drawable/button_onclick"` line from your layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#C7C7C7"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.kisirdongu.denemeapp.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
```